Почему дефис так называется и когда это слово стали использовать в школьной литературе?
В Сети обсуждается вопрос о дефисе и тире. Раньше эти знаки назывались черта и черточка, но когда именно изменилось название в школьных учебниках?
Из словаря:
Дефис. Заимств. в XIX в. из нем. яз., где Divis «тире, дефис» < лат. divisio «разделение».
Тире. Заимств. в XIX в. из франц. яз., где tiret — суф. производное от tirer «тянуть, вытягивать». Тире (по сравнению с дефисом) «более вытянуто».
Меня заинтересовало название. Дефис по этимологии — это разделительный знак, но ведь обычно он используется как соединительный: ПАС § 118. Следующие разряды слов пишутся через дефис: крепко-крепко,терем-теремок, худо-бедно и т. д.
Есть ли тут противоречие или ситуацию можно как-то объяснить?

Gpt chat

Этимология "дефиса" и его роль. Действительно, слово "дефис" происходит от латинского divisio — «разделение», и на первый взгляд это может показаться противоречивым, потому что дефис чаще соединяет части сложных слов и выражений (как в примерах из ПАС). Но исторически дефис воспринимался именно как разделительный знак, указывающий на границу между частями сложных конструкций или смысловых частей, что может считаться способом визуального разделения элементов для облегчения восприятия.

Почему дефис можно считать "разделительным знаком". Важно понимать, что в языках, где использовался дефис, он изначально обозначал разрывы или паузы на стыке частей слов или фраз. В таком контексте дефис выступал как визуальный "разделитель", показывающий некое структурное разделение, даже если в русском языке его применяют для соединения частей сложных слов. Пример из немецкого и французского показывает это значение (defis/divis): визуально знак помогает читателю различить части, не превращая их в слитное слово.

Как дефис стал "соединительным" знаком. Со временем, особенно в русском языке, дефис действительно закрепился как способ объединять части сложных слов и выражений. И хотя он выполняет соединительную функцию, с точки зрения логики это как бы "разделяющее объединение": знак остаётся на стыке, намечая границу и одновременно связывая элементы. В этом можно видеть некоторую двойственность, но всё же это вполне объяснимая эволюция.

История изменений в школьных учебниках. Конкретный момент, когда в школьных учебниках закрепились современные термины "дефис" и "тире", сложно определить точно, но это произошло в советский период, примерно в 1940-1960-е годы. Тогда стандарт языковых норм значительно унифицировался, и заимствования, как "дефис" и "тире", стали активно вытеснять более старые термины "черта" и "черточка", сделав их частью стандартной орфографии. Этот процесс связан с общим стремлением к унификации языка и письменности, а также с влиянием научных грамматик, которые старались создать единообразие в терминах.


Заключение: Противоречие, на первый взгляд, кажется, но объясняется тем, что "дефис" остался визуальным разделителем, даже если выполняет функцию соединения.

Спасибо, Серж, все мне нравится, но неясные вопросы еще остались. Чуть позже я добавлю материал, который мне удалось найти по этой теме. А пока к вам такой вопрос. По графике дефис обозначает нечто среднее между слитным и раздельным написанием слов, то есть совмещает функции разделения и соединения. Но по смыслу это обычно соединительный знак. А можно ли найти примеры слов, где дефис и по смыслу знак разделительный?

Если слово пишется через дефис, то оно выражает какой-то ЦЕЛЬНЫЙ смысл в любом случае. Если словосочетание пишется через пробел, то опять таки оно имеет ЦЕЛЬНЫЙ смысл: красная ручка, перекати через поле итд. Так что вопрос не очень четко поставлен


ПОЧЕМУ ДЕФИС ТАК НАЗЫВАЕТСЯ?..

Из справочника [Коломнин Петр Петрович. Краткие сведения по типографскому делу. Санкт-Петербург, 1899]:

…Дефисом же (от латинского — divisus — раздел) знак называется потому, что при переносе слов из строки в строку их приходится делить на части (слоги).



…И КОГДА ЭТО СЛОВО СТАЛИ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ В ШКОЛЬНОЙ ЛИТЕРАТУРЕ?

Как минимум в 1944 году этот термин школьникам уже был известен.
Из словаря [Ушаков Д.Н., Крючков С.Е. Орфографический словарь : Для нач. семилет. и сред. школы; 6-е изд., испр. и доп. - Москва : Учпедгиз, 1944]:


У НЕЙРОСЕТИ такой ответ: Термин «дефис» пришёл в русскую науку значительно позднее: до 30-х годов XX века в лингвистических работах этот знак называли «чёрточкой». Слово «дефис» вошло в русский язык во второй половине XIX века, но употреблялось исключительно как типографский термин. // Значит, раньше 1944 года.  Но КОГДА они в учебниках поменялись местами: дефис (черточка).

И насколько корректна такая замена. то есть знак с соединительной функцией мы называем  разделительным,  да еще бывшим знаком переноса? Неясные вопросы остаются)

@Sharon НЕЙРОСЕТИ! Некорректно ссылаться на сведения, предоставленные ИИ. Их надлежит проверять и ссылаться на источник

Вот и проверяйте, если надлежит, какие проблемы?  Кстати, нейросети в своих ответах всегда дают ссылки на источники, в отличие от многих наших отвечающих. Поэтому всем рекомендую, качественный информационный сервис.

@Sharon нет такого сервиса "Нейросети". Их много разных. И если бы вы с ними работали, знали бы, что не каждая даст ссылки (это на ваше самоуверенное "всегда"). А источники у них часто вымышленные, часто некорректные., как и ответы в целом Это инструмент, требующий разумного критического подхода, а не вашего. Раньше мода была "раз в интернете написали, значит правда". Ныне новая глупость: "я у нейросети спросила".

@Третийглаз <<нет такого сервиса "Нейросети">> - где вы видите "сервис "Нейросети""? Это вы сами выдумали и сами опровергли. Умно конечно, но не особо: пишите глупости, а потом доказываете, что это глупость. Не лучше ли попробовать написать что-то умное?

@Буратино 4 человека, лайкнувших мой комментарий, не только увидели слово "сервис", но и согласились со мной. Ваши эмоции, обусловленные, вероятно, симпатией к шарон, а не логикой, мне не интересны.

@Третийглаз причём тут количество лайкнувших, если ваш комментарий не дружит с логикой? Может вы сами себя залайкали, наделав аккаунтов? С чего вы решили, что если кто-то проголосовал, огн согласился, может это просто троллинг?

@Буратино свои "может" оставьте при себе. Это форум русского языка, а не паранойи. Не занимайтесь флудом и провокацией

@Третийглаз так вот именно, милый мой, займитесь лучше обсуждением темы, а не флудом, провокациями, хамством и приписыванием выдуманных вами глупостей другим.

Я вам не милый. Научитесь читать и вникать, если вы, конечно, не очередной аккаунт Шарон, что, впрочем, мне не интересно. Умные люди поняли суть претензии к непроверенным ответам, сгенерированым ИИ. Вы сумели только нафлудить, мол, наехали на вашу любимицу. По факту где ваша конкретная претензия? Словом "глупость"? Нет! Где обоснование? Где конкретика? Аргументы детсада. Ещё пальцем начните показывать на тех, кто вас обидел. Вот он и есть флуд. Это серьёзный форум. Если уж кому и заниматься обсуждением темы, то начните с себя.

• Термин "дефис" использовался в словарях уже в 1938 году (ОС Д. Н. Ушакова; подписан в печать 23.12.1937 г.).
Из важнейших правил правописания:

41. Пол (половина) следует писать с черточкой (дефисом) перед гласными буквами и перед л: пол-яблока, пол-листа...

• В 1952 году (ОС Д. Н. Ушакова и С. Е. Крючкова) — тоже еще "симбиоз" терминов:

50. Пол (половина) следует писать с чёрточкой (дефисом) перед гласными буквами и перед л: пол-яблока, пол-листа...

• А вот орфографический словарь под редакцией С. И. Ожегова и А. Б. Шапиро ориентировался уже на "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации", утвержденные и изданные в 1956 году (АН СССР, Институт языкознания, 110 тысяч слов, 1957 г.).
И в нем уже нет никаких черточек.
[Интересно, что в подготовке принимал участие зам. главного редактора журнала "Русский язык в школе" кандидат филологических наук Д. Э. Розенталь.]
Приложение. Правила русской орфографии:

§ 79. Пишутся через дефис:
<...>
12. Пол- (половина) с последующим родительным падежом существительного, если существительное начинается с гласной буквы или согласной л, например: пол-оборота, пол-яблока, пол-лимона...

✦ Так что, думаю, именно в это время — в самом конце пятидесятых — с помощью новых орфографических правил и, возможно, с помощью старейшего научно-методического журнала в России "Русский язык в школе" дефис "перекочевал" и в школьные учебники.

ИНФОРМАЦИОННЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ

Тире было названо знаком препинания в 1802 годе, это уже не черта.

Согласно источнику, терминологическая номинация «тире», под которой понимается знак препинания, предположительно появляется впервые в 1802 году в «Немецкой грамматике» И. Гейма.
Первая лексикографическая фиксация термина отмечена в «Карманной книжке для любителей чтения русских книг…» И. Ренофанца и датирована 1837 годом. В этом случае речь идёт только о фиксации плана выражения термина, но не плана его содержания, поскольку под тире Ренофанц понимает дефис.
Термин «тире» в историко-лингвистической и лексикографической ретроспективе  https://languagejournal.spbu.ru/article/view/18561

Термин «дефис» пришёл в русскую науку значительно позднее: до 30-х годов XX века в лингвистических работах этот знак называли «чёрточкой». Слово «дефис» вошло в русский язык во второй половине XIX века, но употреблялось исключительно как типографский термин. Впервые это слово встречается в «Кратком руководстве для наборщиков типографского искусства» А. Серкова (1861)

Из ответа на  vk.com https://vk.com/wall-138264451_7235


В пособиях по орфографии и в старинных букварях (18-19 вв.) дефис именовали как знак единительства. Для уточнения графического облика этого орфографического знака его часто называли «черточкой».
Со временем начали появляться и первые уточнения по регулированию употребления дефиса. Так академик Я. Грот (19 в.) рекомендовал использовать этот знак:
 - между двумя существительными, которые представляют собой 
 одно слово (генерал-майор, баба-яга, царь-птица);
 - между словами, которые не пишутся вместе, но выступают в 
 роли одного понятия (из-за, что-то, какой-то);
 - между двумя наречиями, которые по смыслу представлены как 
 одно целое (просто-напросто, мало-мальски, давным-давно).

В современном русском языке и по сей день действуют некоторые правила Грота по употреблению дефиса.
Позже добавлю материал из статьи "Многоликий дефис", пока не успела разобраться.

Sharon: «Со временем начали появляться и первые уточнения по регулированию употребления дефиса. Так академик Я. Грот (19 в.) рекомендовал использовать этот знак…» === По-моему, Грот этот знак называл всё же не дефисом (а ведь именно об этом термине Ваш вопрос), а черточкой. Да и термина тире в его книгах я не нашёл (может, и пропустил ненароком). У Грота — черта.

Хотя нет, термин  тире Гротом вскользь упоминается: «Кроме перечисленных главных знаков препинания, одинаковое с ними назначение имеет черта, или тире». Но далее в правилах Грот использует только термин черта: «Иногда черта заменяет запятую…», «Черта может ставиться…», «От черты должно отличать черточку…»
